# s3cmd - delete failed multipart uploads taking up space and being charged

Tags: upload, aws-cli, s3cmd

I use s3cmd for backing up files to AWS S3.

Because of regular internet connection problems, 1000s of failed multipart uploads have built up and I am being charged for this space usage.

I have found a way to list all the multipart uploads and think these are the ones which have failed.

e.g.

```
s3cmd multipart s3://my.bucket.name/
...
2019-09-21T02:57:09.000Z        s3://my.bucket.name/server1/home/jbloggs/bigfile.tar.gz wsmw7IGcBvy.yssRikscDwxozV0_7iU_YXsgwqR3nQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxkPeUiWMp3G6NMWOemaIcWjYA5XaGaiqz09WJKnQRzJIAtQ
```

Is there a way to delete all these failed uploads and stop being charged?

Thanks,

Paully

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
s3cmd --help
```

to see all the options that are available for the tool.

In your case, the `multipart` command will list all the active "incomplete" multipart download.
In the reply, you will see the "object path" and an "upload id".

To "cancel"(ie delete), this incomplete upload, you just have to use the `abortmp`.
In your case, for example, it will be:

```
s3cmd abortmp  s3://my.bucket.name/server1/home/jbloggs/bigfile.tar.gz wsmw7IGcBvy.yssRikscDwxozV0_7iU_YXsgwqR3nQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxkPeUiWMp3G6NMWOemaIcWjYA5XaGaiqz09WJKnQRzJIAtQ

(ie s3cmd abortmp s3://mybucket/myobject Upload_ID)
```